# override bootstrap container width

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, width

I have an easy HTML template using bootstrap 3. Template has following structure: static header, static footer and content which is in the bootstrap's class "Container". In the middle of content I have bootstrap'w "Well" and i want it make looks like header and footer. I mean I want it to be the full width of the screen on any screen.

I created easy [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jC7af/6/)

Here's a question, is there any way to override container's width inside this container?

```
<header>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="content">

      </div>
      <div class="well">

      </div>
      <div class="content">

      </div>
   </div>
<footer>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused ... you want `.well` to extend to the edges of the screen?

Comment: Why don't you close the `.container` before the `.well` and open it right after? I mean, just remove the `.well` from the `.container`.

Comment: Explosion Pills, added image for greater understanding

Comment: azeós, read answer under stroypixel's post. I need only one container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ORIGINAL + BEST PRACTICE: always move the `.well` outside of `.container` to stay idiomatic with Bootstrap.

UPDATE + IF ABOVE IS NOT AN OPTION: Given that you cannot easily modify `.container` styles and/or move the `.well` outside of `.container`, your best bet is JavaScript. Here I have made a script that makes `.well` expand as the width of the window changes.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamnotsam/E3RQp/1/)

The idea is that you want a negative value for `margin-left` and `margin-right` so that `.well` expands across the screen.

Comment: It is not useful to me.The problem is that must be only one class Container. And all divs are inside this class. Cause I have one layout template that has class Container, and I paste inside this layout content from other pages.

Comment: Got it. I am updating my answer now. One sec

Answer (score 21):

Here theres a simpler trick that works like a charm: https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Look for: "No calc() needed"

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="well full-width"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>
```

CSS

```
.full-width {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

Comment: This works great, except I had to set width: 99.4vw so it didn't go off the page, why is that? But as soon as I downsize the screen size, then the percentage that it's off gets a little greater.

Comment: Thanks for only CSS solution.

Comment: With Yii : $this->registerCss('.full-width { width: 100vw; position: relative; left: 50%; right: 50%; margin-left: -50vw; margin-right: -50vw; } ');, it's perfect!

Answer (score 15):

The div `container` has the following `max-width` specified in media query as default by bootstrap.

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .container{
    max-width:750px;
  }  
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
  .container{
    max-width:970px;
  }
}
```

To override this add the below style in your stylesheet

// This should be added in default styles, not within media query
   .container{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
   }

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .container{
    max-width:100%;
  }  
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
  .container{
    max-width:100%;
  }
}
```