# Bootstrap css: make .col fluid inside .container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, fluid

I have a problem in bootstrap css about container and fluid

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border:3px solid black"><- this div still here</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border:3px solid red">this div full to right -></div>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border:3px solid black">text here</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border:3px solid red">text here</div>
</div>
```

I make it on JSFiddle too, please look it for detail:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n0afa0qm/3/)

my problem is, how to make my `col-sm-6` inside container like `col-sm-6` inside `container-fluid`. Or anyone have other way to fix it?

Comment: So why you use `.container` if you want to behave it like `.container-fluid`?

Comment: i need container for fix left position but i need a right side like width 100% following container fluid. look detail on my jsfiddle @makshh

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post can help you: [override bootstrap container width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996429/override-bootstrap-container-width)

The idea is basically that you put negative `margin` on your `div`.